# Override row color on a single row inside a table with alternating row colors

Tags: html, css

I've got a table with CSS3 alternating row styles but I need to override the styling for a few rows.

Here is the CSS for the table:

```
table.primary tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
table.primary tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ededed;
}
```

I need to override some rows with a very different background-color (and other formatting), and I was hoping to just add a `class=` to the individual rows, but it appears that this does not override the above CSS.

e.g.

```
<table class="primary">
    <tr><td>one</td></tr>
    <tr class="new"><td>two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>three</td></tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively I'll need to skip CSS3 and just use a `class="row1"`, `class="row2"`, `class="new"` instead.

Any suggestions on how to override the `nth-child` with a class?

Comment: What code did you put in your stylesheet for your new class names?  Was it just .row1, or was is table.primary tr... etc?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As classes and pseudo-classes share the same specificity, it should be enough to define the `.new` style rule *after* the `:nth-child()` rules like this, assuming a single class is to overidde all other styles:

```
table.primary tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
table.primary tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ededed;
}
table.primary tr.new {
    background-color: #ffc;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/WESta)

Comment: Thank you! this fixed the problem.  I had the tr.new class BEFORE the nth-child classes.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
table.primary tr.new:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #ff0000;
}
table.primary tr.new:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you know you can put multiple css statements into one class right? then you can override with !important when needed :)

here is a JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dJWR2/

Comment: Seriously? `class="odd even"` with an `!important` rule for `.even`?

Comment: I mean, it's nonsensical to call an element number odd *and* even.

Comment: Just to add, the important was for demonstration as the OP said other styling was needing to be overridden also. Its a simple js fiddle.

Comment: Maybe I could of changed the names a little - but Im sure you get the idea :P

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the opening `td` tag from the second row.

Then follow BoltClock's instructions :)

Comment: thanks, that was just a quick oversight from typing the question - if I pasted the original table it would have been way too much code to make the question easy to read ;)